# <your user home>/AppData/Roaming/MikTex<your user home>/AppData/Roaming/MikTexHow do I get around TeXworks crash after bMiKTeX reinstall

Tags: texworks, miktex2.9

After I reinstalled MiKTex on a Vista system using basic-miktex from CTAN and starting TeXworks, I got the message

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt
platform plugin "windows"
in "".
```

/AppData/Roaming does not have a MikTex directory.

I suspect that uninstalling MiKTeX remove the QT support from windows, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: According to https://miktex.org/kb/prerequisites vista is not supported. You could try to install more packages with the package manager, perhaps you then get the missing library. Or try another editor.

Comment: That's why I got an older version from CTAN. https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex says "A dis­tri­bu­tion of TeX and friends for Win­dows 2000, XP, Vista and Win­dows 7, as well as Win­dows Server 2003 and 2008."

Comment: The CTAN version is the newest, and the text is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Does anybody know where I can get the most recent distribution that supports vista?

Comment: I'm frustrated because of this. Why the hell doesn't Miktex tell you that trying to update will end in corrupted installation that is not fixable since your OS is not supported any more.